# jquery toggleClass does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a photogallery, using jquery. Here is my code

```
//css
<style>
.details{display:none;}
</style>

//html
 <div class="photo">
            <img src="meAndImogenPoots.jpg">
            <div class="details">
                Me and Imogen Poots
            </div>
</div>

//jquery
$('.photo').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass($(this).find('.details'));
});
```

I want to toggle the `details class` of every photo, when a mouseenter occurs. So I will put a `toggleClass` inside the `mouseenter` callback function, right?But this does not work, I get no errors on my console. What am I missing?

Comment: What `$(this).toggleClass($(this).find('.details'));` supposed to do?

Comment: @j08691 Toggle the particular `details class` of the particular `photo class`. This is what I thought

Comment: Check out the docs for `.toggleClass()`. It takes one or more class names, but you're feeding it a jQuery object.

Comment: @j08691. Thanks for the info. Why `$(this).find('.details')` is an object? Should it be just a class name? And , is there a way to convert it from an object to a simple string? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hover()` instead of `mouseenter()`.

And use jQuery to hide `.details` instead of doing it through `CSS`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".details").hide();
    $(".photo").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.details').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6xXpj/7/)**

Comment: the second time the mouse enters `.photo`, `$(this).find('.details')` will return `[]`. Here really, you should have a way to target the inner div other than with the class name you're toggling.

Answer (score 1):

DEMO -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6xXpj/2/**

Add another class `innerDiv` to the div and use it to toggle

```
<div class="photo">
    <img src="meAndImogenPoots.jpg">
    <div class="innerDiv details">Me and Imogen Poots</div>
</div>

$('.photo').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.innerDiv').toggleClass('details');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `.details { display: none }`, and are simply showing/hiding the text when hover over the image, here's what I would do.

```
$('.photo img').on
({
    mouseenter: function () { $(this).parent().find(".details").show(); },
    mouseleave: function () { $(this).parent().find(".details").hide(); }
});
```

[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eXR78/)

Answer (score 0):

Krishna's answer requires less modification to my original code. imbondbaby's answer requires less code and less chaining inside the callback function. So here is a combination of those two

html and css part remain the same, only jquery changes to this :

```
$('.photo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('.details').toggle();
});
```

I also had to add a `bind` to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, to toggle the class when those events occure and also keep the code small, compact and clean.

Thanks everyone for your answers, time and effort :)

Comment: @imbondbaby Unfortunatelly, I cannot accept two answers (yours and krishna's).